# How to print html response (tinymce) in x-editable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tinymce-4, x-editable

Using x-editable and tinymce to edit a field, however the return value is printed showing the html code (with

etc.), when reloading the page it is fine.

example of what is shown when saving the field;

```
<p>this is a test response</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

(instead of)

```
this is a test response
```

Editable initializations code:

```
 $('.editable').editable('option','validate', function (v) {
     if (this.dataset.type == 'textarea') {
        return {newValue: tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()};
     }
 });
```

This is the editable field:

```
    <%= editable @article, :introduction, url: article_update_path(@article), type: 'textarea', onblur: 'ignore' %>
```

I want it to be showing the "html-output" instead of the html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
 $('.editable').editable('option','display', function (value, sourceData) {
     this.innerHTML = value;
 });
```